# where does this prove come from: for any kind of value $s,t,u: s/t \land s/u \Rightarrow s/(t+u)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

Can someone explain me why does this arithmetic theory comes from : $s,t,u: s/t \land s/u \Rightarrow s/(t+u)$ in wich s,t,u can have any kind of value.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$s|t$$ then $$t=ms$$ and $$s|u$$ then $$u=ns$$ and we get $$t+u=s(m+n)=sp'$$ where $m,n,p'$ are integers.

Comment: the | :  does it mean s devide by t

Comment: yes that does it mean,$$s|t$$ then $$t=ms$$

Comment: and the word "then" : does it mean \Rightarrow ?

Comment: Yes that does it, then follows .